# How to illustrate playing music notes in UI by reading meta-event of a midi file

Tags: android, midi

[image]

I'm using https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib to read meta-event and get midi data. I think I drew correctly like this but the problem is timing concept. I can't render UI match with playing music, even know BPM, Quarter pulse per note(QPPN), microsecond per quarter note(tempo). Any suggest?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, there is lag time between the time a note is played and the time it is actually played through the speaker. If that's not the problem, please know that your problem is too broad in its current state. You'll need to simplify your problem and also simplify your midi file so that it plays only one single note for a very specific duration to begin with, and nothing else.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk No. It's not about lag time. It's about I don't know how to render a note right in time.

Comment: Render the test midi test file with a midi program on your PC.

Comment: related: [Reading notes from MIDI file using NAudio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23888692/11654)

Comment: Is that a screenshot from your app? it looks great!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: No. But I can draw the same. My problems is just playing match with those shapes. I don't know what to do with BPM, QPPN, tempo even know these numbers.

Comment: So, you lack some music bases... for sure, I ca say that BPM = beats per minute. tempo should be beats per measure, QPPN... never heard . nothing that Google won't help yuou to find. Then the rest is math.