# Read every note from a MIDI file (note, velocity, length) using DryWetMidi

Tags: c#, file, midi

I'm making a C# program that should read every note from a MIDI file and get the length and the velocity of the note, but I don't know how to do that...

I'm using the [DryWetMidi](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library, but is there some other library?

Comment: And your question is? You should reformulate the question and also share the code mentioned.

Comment: I'm making a C# programm that should read every note from a midi file and get the length and the velocity of the note, but I don't know how to do that... _sorry I just noticed that I didn't really ask a question. Fixed it_

Comment: Related: *[Reading notes from MIDI file using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888692/)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the [DryWetMidi 1.1.0](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/releases/tag/v1.1.0), all you need to get notes of a MIDI file is this code:

```
IEnumerable<Note> notes = midiFile.GetNotes();
```

The `Note` class contains all properties you need: `NoteNumber`, `NoteName`, `Octave`, `Length`, `Time`, `Velocity`, and `OffVelocity`.

To get `Time` as *<hours,minutes,seconds>* or *<bars,beats>*, you can use `TimeAs` extension method:

```
TempoMap tempoMap = midiFile.GetTempoMap();
MetricTimeSpan metricTime = note.TimeAs<MetricTimeSpan>(tempoMap);
BarBeatTicksTimeSpan musicalTime = note.TimeAs<BarBeatTicksTimeSpan>(tempoMap);
```

For `Length`, you can use `LengthAs` extension method:

```
TempoMap tempoMap = midiFile.GetTempoMap();
MetricTimeSpan metricLength = note.LengthAs<MetricTimeSpan>(tempoMap);
BarBeatTimeSpan metricLength = note.LengthAs<BarBeatTimeSpan>(tempoMap);
```

You can read more in the [Time and length](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/high-level-managing/Time-and-length.html) article of the library documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23888692/reading-notes-from-midi-file-using-naudio).

Further information can be grabbed [here](https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/562256).

DryWetMidi isn't really clear about the chunk sizes, apart from reading these notes out of the chunk, as far as I've looked into it.